# How can I mirror an SQL Azure Database on a regular windows server?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm considering migrating our existing SaaS website to Windows Azure.

But while Azure looks nice and is probably more stable than a regular Windows server, I still want to to have some kind of backup plan in case that the whole Azure should go down. Call me paranoid, but it has happened for other clouds multiple times before (http://eu.techcrunch.com/2011/04/21/amazon-ec2-goes-down-taking-with-it-reddit-foursquare-and-quora/).

If that should ever happen, I still want to have our single windows server available for hosting our app.

It's not too difficult to deploy to both azure and our own webserver from the same code base, but I am not sure how to go about mirroring the SQL Azure db to my windows server.

Is there any way to do this? Also, what edition of SQL server do I need to on my windows server to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Azure Data SYNC CTP 2 to sync your SQL Azure DB with on premise DB; But Data SYNC is in CTP, so you can you can also use - SQL Azure migration wizard, SSIS, BCP, SQL server import/export, etc to have a backup copy.

Links:

1. SQL Azure migration wizard: http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/
2. SQL Azure DATA SYNC http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sqlazure/datasync/

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you know the minimum required edition of Sql Server I need for Sync to work? More specifically, does it work with Express and Web editions?

Comment: SQL Azure is based on SQL server 2008 code - i suggest using SQL server 2008 express/web or higher edition DB's

Comment: Also the SQL server 2005 DB should work fine. But i do not have experience with it. I have migrated a SQL server 2005 express to SQL Azure using SQL Azure migration wizard but i have not tried it the other way round. you can try it - i think it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [SQL Azure Backup](http://optillect.com/products/sqlazurebackup/overview.html) - this tool allows you create backups as a single file.
And [Data Compare SQL](http://optillect.com/products/datacomparesql/overview.html) synchronizes table data.